# Wordpress get_page_children failing for no reason

Tags: wordpress

I have this code running a sub page navigation in a  wordpress theme.

This is working perfectly elsewhere. This virtually unaltered from the codex page for get_page_children. I have checked `$post->ID, $subpage_query` and `$all_pages` and everything looks fine. It just refuses to populate the `$page` variable for no apparent reason.

```
<div class="sub-pages">

                        <?php
                        $subpage_query = new WP_Query();
                    $all_pages = $subpage_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'date'));
                    $subpages = get_page_children( $post->ID, $all_pages );

                        $pa = 0;
                        foreach ($subpages as $k => $page) {

                            if ($pa > 3) {
                                break;
                            }?>

                            <div class="sub-page">

                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($page -> ID); ?>">
                                <div class="overload"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page -> ID, 'medium'); ?></div>
                                <p><?php echo $page -> post_title; ?></p>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        <?php $pa++; } ?>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$all_pages = $subpage_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'date', 'posts_per_page' => -1)));
```

Comment: can't believe I missed that